# How to import playoff data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import playoff data from this page 
https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/t/thompkl01/gamelog/2019/

I've tried to replicate the same macro I'm using to get season data but changing the number of .webtables from 8 to 9 doesn't return any data.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/ _ 
     t/thompkl01/gamelog/2019/", _
     Destination:=Range("$C$11"))
    .Name = "2019"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = True
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertEntireRows
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "8"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

What's the best solution to get the playoff data?

Comment: You can use `PowerQuery` aka `Get&Transform` to access that table easily.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

You can use scraping tools to achieve your goal which like [dataminer](https://data-miner.io/), [grepsr](https://www.webscraper.io/) etc.

Best Wishes